# Libre Calc / Excel - Как выделить записи по частичным совпадениям?

Tags: excel, office, libre-office

Что бы удалить полные дубликаты: Data -> More filters -> Advanced filter -> Options -> No dublications. Затем необходимо выделить массив (например колонка A) и готово. Выделенный массив выглядит например следующим образом:
$Sheet1.$A$1:$A$5

А как автоматом выделить записи с частичными совпадениями? Например из списка:

- a01
- b01
- c01
- d02
- e03

Как автоматически выделить записи заканчивающиеся на "01"? 
Если это невозможно, то как выделить все записи с количеством совпадений 2,3,4,5 и т.д?

Пользуюсь Libre, но если там никак - Excel как вариант

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Libre Calc* и *Excel* хоть и похожи, но это разные программы и что умеет *Excel*, не всегда умеет сестричка (или *Calc* - братик? :) ).

Все, что ниже, работает в *Excel*.

```
 -----------------------
```

**Вариант1.** Встроенный инструмент *Автофильтр*.

Установить автофильтр: закладка *Данные-Фильтр*.

Далее выбрать фильтрацию по нужному столбцу, *Текстовые_фильтры-Заканчивается_на-01*

```
-----------------------
```

**Вариант2.** *Автофильтр* + функции листа.

В свободном столбце записать формулу:

```
=ПРАВСИМВ(A2;2)="01"
```

Если ищем не только в конце текста, но любое частичное совпадение:

```
=ЕЧИСЛО(ПОИСК("01";A2))

=ДЛСТР(A2)-ДЛСТР(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A2;"01";))<>0
```

Фильтрация в данном случае в столбце с формулой по значению *ИСТИНА*

```
 -----------------------
```

**Вариант3.** Функции листа (без применения фильтра).

```
=ИНДЕКС($A$2:$A$6;НАИМЕНЬШИЙ(ЕСЛИ(ПРАВБ($A$2:$A$6;2)="01";СТРОКА(2:6)-1);СТРОКА(A1)))
```

В свободном диапазоне ввести в первую ячейку. Вводить как формулу массива - тремя клавишами *Ctrl+Shift+Enter*. Протянуть по строкам ниже.

Чтобы избавиться от ошибок в диапазоне ниже полученных значений, можно применить

```
=ЕСЛИОШИБКА(формула;"все кончилось")
```

Для большей гибкости в формулах можно писать ссылку на ячейку, в которой задается искомое

```
 -----------------------
```

**Вариант4.** Использование *VBA.*

*Alt+F11* - вход в редактор *VBA*

Вкладка *Insert-Module* - создание общего модуля.

Раскрыть модуль и разместить там код:

```
Option Explicit

' поиск данных по частичному совпадению
Sub FindData()
Dim ArrData()
Dim sStr As String
Dim lRws As Long
Dim i As Long, k As Long
    With ActiveSheet ' можно подставить имя любого листа- Worksheets("имя")
        sStr = .Range("C1").Value ' искомый текст
        ' последняя заполененная строка столбца А
        lRws = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ' считаем, что в строке 1 шапка таблицы
        If lRws < 2 Then Exit Sub ' данных нет
        ArrData = .Range("A1:A" & lRws).Value ' данные заносим в массив
        ' работа с объектами листа медленная, лучше обрабатывать в памяти

        k = 1: ArrData(1, 1) = "Найденное"

        For i = 2 To lRws ' цикл по данным
            If ArrData(i, 1) Like "*" & sStr Then  ' если искомое в конце значениия
'            If ArrData(i, 1) Like "*" & sStr & "*" Then  ' если искомое содержится в значении
                k = k + 1 ' счетчик найденных значений
                ArrData(k, 1) = ArrData(i, 1) ' записываем значение
            End If
        Next i

        If k > 1 Then
            .Columns(4).ClearContents ' удаляем данные из столбца D
            .Range("D1").Resize(k, 1).Value = ArrData ' выгружаем найденное в столбец D
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

На листе можно создать кнопку (например, *Вставка-Фигуры*), которой присвоить запуск макроса (*ПКМ-Назначить_макрос*).

После запуска данные столбца *А*, в которых найдено искомое, записанное в ячейке *С1*,  будут отображены в столбце *D*